# Hover over the css sprites and text at same time to change color

Tags: html, css

I have a css sprite image and a text besides it. I was wondering how to make a hover on both image and text to make them change the color. Here is the css:

```
span#mail-to {
    background: url("/images/magenta_wpm_icons.png") -24px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 23px;
    height: 15px;
}
a.button-link:hover,
a.button-link:active,
a.button-link:disabled {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #75ba54;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #75ba54 #339933 #006600;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}   
span#mail-to:hover {
    background-position: -24px -27px; 
}
a.button-link {
    padding-left: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id ="mail-to"> </span>                                            
<a class="button-link" href="mailto:">Mail to</a>
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `span` and the `anchor` tags in a `div` and define the hover event on the `div` (rather than individual hover handling on the individual `span` and `anchor` tags).

HTML

```
<div class="mail-button-wrapper">
    <span id ="mail-to"> </span>
    <a class="button-link" href="mailto:">Mail to</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mail-button-wrapper:hover #mail-to {
    // style the span here
}

.mail-button-wrapper:hover a.button-link {
    // style the anchor tag here
}
```

Also:  you don't need to say `span#mail-to`.  just say `#mail-to`.
Identifiers are unique, so adding `span` doesn't make the reference any more specific than having the id on its own.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. but there is a delay when the hover happens on both text and image. It first changes the image color and in a delay of 1sec changes the text color.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and suggestion. However it seems like there is still delay in time when the change color happens on image and text. it first changes the color of the image and after a delay of 1 sec changes the text color. I'm baffled as to why it is happening so.

Comment: @user2942566 - can you create a jsfiddle or share a link to site that shows the delay?

Comment: Could you show an example in either jsfiddle or codepen, please? It would be helpful to see the code in action.